# Search a space after a particular string in java

Tags: java

```
 String text = "select ename from emp";
```

I want to know the space index after the word **from**. How to do it?

Comment: You could start by reading through the [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're specifically looking for the index of the first space after the word "from", you can use:

```
text.substring(text.indexOf("from")).indexOf(' ');
```

If you're trying to do something more general, than you'll need to give a bit more information. But the indexOf() method will probably be very useful to you.

Edit: This should actually be

```
text.indexOf(' ', text.indexOf("from"));
```

The first version returns the index relative to "from", whereas the second returns the index relative to the original string. (thanks @jpm)

This loop will find all space characters in the given string:

```
int index = text.indexOf(' ');
while (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println(index);
    index = text.indexOf(' ', index + 1);
}
```

Comment: Even better, `text.indexOf(' ', text.indexOf("from"));`. Your solution will give the index of the space relative to from, not the absolute index.

Comment: Thanks drewhannay can you tell me how to get the indexs of a space in the string text i mean i should get the output as:6,12,17

Answer (score 1):

The very basic answer might look something like...

```
String text = "select ename from emp";

text = text.toLowerCase();
if (text.contains("from ")) {
    int index = text.indexOf("from ") + "from".length();
    System.out.println("Found space @ " + index);
    System.out.println(text.substring(index));
} else {
    System.out.println(text + " does not contain `from `");
}
```

Or you could use some regular expression (this is a rather poor example, but hay)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("from ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

String match = null;

int endIndex = -1;

if (matcher.find()) {

    endIndex = matcher.end();

}

if (endIndex > -1) {
    endIndex--;
    System.out.println("Found space @ " + endIndex);
    System.out.println(text.substring(endIndex));
} else {
    System.out.println(text + " does not contain `from `");
}
```

To find the index of each space you could do something like...

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

String match = null;

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

Which will output

```
6
12
17
```

Comment: @AmitD if you can't dazzle with brilliance, baffle with bull s**t

Answer (score -2):

use indexOf() method. Hope u got the answer